# Can't use xlsxwriter with gzip.open

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to write a compressed excel file,

```
import xlsxwriter
import gzip

fp = gzip.open('test.xlsx.gz', 'wb')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fp, {'constant_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet")
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'test')
workbook.close()
```

And it results in an exception,

```
OSError: Negative seek in write mode
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: You cannot unzip and write to an xlsx file like that. An xlsx file is a collection of zipped XML files and they need to be parsed and rewritten. Also, XlsxWriter can only create new files. Try OpenPyXL instead. That can modify existing files.